# MVC5/razor - Login Password asterisks appearing on Change Password form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

On my Change Password form I have asterisks appearing in the New Password field. I assume they are appearing as a leftover from the password field from the Login Form?

**Change Password form (partial):**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-3 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
    </div>
</div>
```

This behavior is probably browser-related due to a cookie from saving the password on login. I'm just wondering if there is anyway to overcome this without renaming the Password field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Html.PasswordFor` (and all of the other  `xxxFor` HtmlHelpers) will fill in the input field with whatever value the model has for the property when the page is rendered.  In this case, `Model.Password` must already have a value, perhaps from when you fetched the user from the database.  Note, if you are storing the user's password somewhere in plain text, this is bad practice.

Before the call to `View` in your Controller, clear out the `Password` property.

If that doesn't work and you've confirmed the `Password` property of the Model is empty when the page loads, then perhaps it is some browser autocompletion as you say.  You can try adding `autocomplete = "off"` attribute to the input element.

Comment: Using TextBoxFor shows the password in plain text which would be inconsistent with every other password-related field on the site. I want the asterisks - I just don't want a bunch of asterisks in that field on a freshly rendered page. An asterisk should appear for every character typed.

Comment: @nwkiii my mistake, misunderstood your problem.  Updated my answer.

Comment: Bort, autocomplete = "off" resolved the problem. Thanks.